# XML scanning for value

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML with the following structure that I'm getting from an API -

```
<entry>
    <id>2397</id>
    <title>action_alert</title>
    <tes:actions>
        <tes:name>action_alert</tes:name>
        <tes:type>2</tes:type>
    </tes:actions>
</entry>
```

I am scanning for the ID by doing the following -

```
sourceobject = etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(fullsourceurl))
source_id = sourceobject.xpath('//id/text()')[0]
```

I also want to get the tes:type

```
source_type = sourceobject.xpath('//tes:actions/tes:type/text()')[0]
```

Doesn't work.  It gives the following error -

lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix

How do I get it to ignore the namespace?

Alternatively, I know the namespace which is this -

```
<tes:action xmlns:tes="http://www.blah.com/client/servlet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to access nodes in namespace is by passing prefix-namespace URL mapping as additional argument to `xpath()` method, for example :

```
ns = {'tes' : 'http://www.blah.com/client/servlet'}
source_type = sourceobject.xpath('//tes:actions/tes:type/text()', namespaces=ns)
```

Or, another way which is less recommended, by literally ignoring namespaces using xpath function `local-name()` :

```
source_type = sourceobject.xpath('//*[local-name()="actions"]/*[local-name()="type"]/text()')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about the namespace thing, but I think it would be easier to use [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):
(`text` is the text)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

ids = []
get_ids = soup.find_all("id")
for tag in get_ids:
    ids.append(tag.text)

#ids is now ['2397']

types = []
get_types = soup.find_all("tes:actions")
for child in get_types:
    type = child.find_all("tes:type")
    for tag in type:
        types.append(tag.text)

#types is now ['2']
```